# How to set variable in jQuery so that it doesn't autorun?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to refactor my code to not repeat and to make it more clear. I was trying to set a variable like so:

```
var activatedLikeIcon = $(this).closest('.pic-section').find('.like-button').css({
    'background-position-x': '-155px',
    'background-position-y': '-229px'
});
```

The issue is that the background position properties are changed when the variable is set??? This code is nested in an if statement and should only run under certain criteria, yet it changes the properties no matter what. Any insight would be super helpful. Thanks!

PS: if the .css(STUFF) is substituted for `.hide()`, the same phenomenon occurs and the div is hidden as soon as the variable is set.

The following code is the entire JS for reference (I have commented out the variable and code in question. I wanted to substitute that variable into the code to replace where the code is currently being used to make things more readable):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var defaultValue,
        defaultColor,
        flashHeartActivateLikeIconAndAddToLikeCount = function() {
            var likeCount = $(this).closest('.pic-section').find('.like-count'),
                likeIcon = $(this).closest('.pic-section').find('.like-button');
            if (+likeCount.text() === 0) {
                $(this).closest('.pic-section').prepend('<div class="heart"></div>');
                $('.heart').delay(300).fadeOut();
                likeCount.text(1)
            } else {
                likeCount.text(0);
                $('.heart').remove();
            }
            if (likeIcon.css('background-position-x') === '-276px') {
                likeIcon.css({
                    'background-position-x': '-155px',
                    'background-position-y': '-229px'
                });
            } else {
                likeIcon.css({
                    'background-position-x': '-276px',
                    'background-position-y': '-180px'
                });
            }
        },
        activateLikeIconAndAddToLikeCount = function() {
            var likeCount = $(this).closest('.pic-section').find('.like-count'),
                likeIcon = $(this).closest('.pic-section').find('.like-button');
                // activatedLikeIcon = likeIcon.css({
                //     'background-position-x': '-155px',
                //     'background-position-y': '-229px'
                // }); => adding this code causes the background positions to change immediately
                if (likeIcon.css('background-position-x') === '-276px') {
                    likeIcon.css({
                        'background-position-x': '-155px',
                        'background-position-y': '-229px'
                    });
                    likeCount.text(1);
                } else {
                    likeIcon.css({
                        'background-position-x': '-276px',
                        'background-position-y': '-180px'
                    });
                    likeCount.text(0);
                }
        },
        clearValueAndChangeToBlack = function() {
            defaultValue = $(this).val();
            defaultColor = $(this).css('color');
            $(this).css('color', 'black');
            if ($(this).val() === defaultValue) $(this).val('');
        },
        addDefaultValueAndChangeToGray = function() {
            if ($(this).val().length === 0) {
                $(this).val(defaultValue);
                $(this).css('color', defaultColor);
            }
        },
        submitWithEnter = function(key) {
            if (key.which === 13) {
                var str = $(this).closest('.pic-section').find('input').val();
                $(this).css('color', 'rgb(153, 153, 153)');
                $(this).closest('.pic-section').find('.comments').append('<div class="new-comment"><b>ctoppel</b> ' + str + '</div>');
                $(this).val('Add a comment...');
                $(this).blur();
            }
        };
    $.get('https://codesmith-precourse.firebaseio.com/instagram/-JqL35o8u6t3dTQaFXSV.json', function(data) {
        var user = "<div class='pic-user'><div class='avatar'></div>ctoppel</div>",
            time = "<div class='pic-time'>2d</div>",
            header = "<div class='pic-header'>" + user + time + "</div>",
            likes = "<div class='likes'><span class='like-count'>0</span> likes</div>",
            comments = "<div class='comments'></div>",
            addComment = "<div class='add-comment'><div class='like-button'></div><input class='comment-input' name='comment' value='Add a comment...'></input></div>",
            footer = "<div class='pic-footer'>" + likes + comments + addComment + "</div>";
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            function testImage(URL) {
                var tester = new Image();
                tester.onload = imageFound;
                tester.src = URL;
            }

            function imageFound(pic) {
                $('.feed-container').append('<div class="pic-section">' + header + '<img src="' + pic.currentTarget.src + '">' + footer + '</div>');
            }
            testImage(data[i]);
        };
    });
    $('.feed-container').on('dblclick', 'img', flashHeartActivateLikeIconAndAddToLikeCount);
    $('.feed-container').on('click', '.like-button', activateLikeIconAndAddToLikeCount);
    $('.feed-container').on('focus', 'input', clearValueAndChangeToBlack);
    $('.feed-container').on('focusout', 'input', addDefaultValueAndChangeToGray);
    $('.feed-container').on('keypress', 'input', submitWithEnter);
});
```

Comment: Can you add more context to your JS

Comment: Do you need to set it as a variable? Can you not just have a statement: `$(this).closest('.pic-section').find('.like-button').css({ 'background-position-x': '-155px', 'background-position-y': '-229px' }`

Comment: Get object first and then set initial value x and y to another variables.

Comment: think you should edit your question, and let us know what are you trying to do instead.

Comment: I have edited my question to show the full code and to hopefully clarify my issue. It may be that I can't set such code to a variable, but I was hoping that I could to make things more readable.